# Sort file which is too large to fit in memory in Java

Tags: java

I have a task to sort text file by parts.
My approach so far is wrong:

1. read input file by parts - i.e.read 1/10 for each iteration.
2. sort each part
3. read 1 line from each file and sort them between each other. (and so on till - read each last line from each file)
4. write batches from step 3 to final file.

The problem here is sorting is wrong in final file and I do understand it should be wrong in current approach. But I can't get how to make correct sorting here.

Answer (score 0):

1, 2, and 4 is fine.

3 is the problem: Imagine:

- batch1: [A, B]
- batch2: [E, G]
- batch3: [D, F]

in this case taking the first entry of all batches (A/E/D), sorting those, and writing them out is a mistake. You need to iterate all batches simultaneously. Start each batch on the first item:

- batch1 = A
- batch2 = E
- batch3 = D

Then write, the 'lowest' of them all and advance that one. So, write 'A', and advance b1:

- batch1 = B
- batch2 = E
- batch3 = D

Write the lowest again, and advance the pointer:

- batch1 = [ended]
- batch2 = E
- batch3 = D

Then:

- batch1 = [ended]
- batch2 = E
- batch3 = F

Then:

- batch1 = [ended]
- batch2 = G
- batch3 = F

etc, until they have all ended.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost right, the problem is you are assuming that a first elements of each part is greater/lower than the second one of each.

Let's consider an example:

```
File1: [ 0, 0, 0 ]
File2: [ 10, 10, 10]

ResultFile: [10, 0, 10, 0, 10, 0]
```

The "merge" those files into one which is ordered, we need to compare first elements of each list, but append only the lowest/biggest in each iteration.

It could be something like here (but, I wrote it in Kotlin as it has some nice methods for lists). Should be not a problem to translate it to Java.

```kotlin
class ResultFile {
    val file: File = TODO()

    fun append(s: Any) {
        // Append to file
    }
}

class SortedFile {
    val file: File = TODO()

    fun length(): Int {
        // return wc of file
        return 0
    }

    fun pop(): Int {
        // remove first line and return it
        return 0
    }

    fun peek(): Int {
        // get head of file
        return 0
    }
}

fun getPartFile(): List<SortedFile> {
    // split a file, sort parts, return them
    return listOf()
}

fun sort() {
    val files: List<SortedFile> = getPartFile()
    val resultFile: ResultFile = ResultFile()

    while (files.any { it.length() > 0 }) {
        // Create temporary list with sorted by peek and the first one
        val s = files.filter { it.length() > 0 }.minBy { it.peek() }!!
        resultFile.append(s.pop())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Sort each file separately
2. Now read a next line from each file
3. sort these lines (1 from each file)
4. insert top line in output file
5. again read a line from file, whose line was written in output file
6. repeat steps 3 to 5 till end of all files

Note : In case of EOF stop reading from that file

Hopes that helps